# Host react app on github pages, shows default MD of built app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I was trying to deploy my react app to github pages in order to show to a a recruiter this 'test' I saw you can do this using `gh-pages` package but when I deploy it to the gh-pages branch and go to the url of the github page I just can see the default md that is shown when you use the `yarn build` command i.e this :

```
Getting Started with Create React App

This project was bootstrapped with Create React App.
Available Scripts

In the project directory, you can run:
npm start

Runs the app in the development mode.
Open http://localhost:3000 to view it in your browser.

The page will reload when you make changes.
You may also see any lint errors in the console.
npm test

Launches the test runner in the interactive watch mode.
See the section about running tests for more information.
npm run build

Builds the app for production to the build folder.
It correctly bundles React in production mode and optimizes the build for the best performance.

The build is minified and the filenames include the hashes.
Your app is ready to be deployed!

See the section about deployment for more information.
npm run eject

Note: this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!

If you aren’t satisfied with the build tool and configuration choices, you can eject at any time. This command will remove the single build dependency from your project.

Instead, it will copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you have full control over them. All of the commands except eject will still work, but they will point to the copied scripts so you can tweak them. At this point you’re on your own.

You don’t have to ever use eject. The curated feature set is suitable for small and middle deployments, and you shouldn’t feel obligated to use this feature. However we understand that this tool wouldn’t be useful if you couldn’t customize it when you are ready for it.
Learn More

You can learn more in the Create React App documentation.

To learn React, check out the React documentation.
Code Splitting

This section has moved here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/code-splitting
Analyzing the Bundle Size

This section has moved here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size
Making a Progressive Web App

This section has moved here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app
Advanced Configuration

This section has moved here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration
Deployment

This section has moved here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment
npm run build fails to minify

This section has moved here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify
```

the steps I followed was:

1. run the `yarn build` command,
2. copied the build folder to the gh-pages branch
3. erased the src folder and deployed to github.
4. automatically the page was configured on github pages to be served from gh-pages branch but was shown the above md instead my app.

my package.json file is this, here I also created the predeploy and deploy script.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "persona-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.3",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "serve": "^14.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

how can I fix this issue? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you change the branch in the github pages options? `https://github.com/username/reponame/settings/pages`

Comment: yes, it was done automatically, it is serving the page from the gh-pages branch